# How To Use Firebase RTDB with Flutter Stream

Tags: firebase, flutter

Is there any way to use firebase RTDB(not FireStore) with Flutter Stream Builder. I search many times but I cannot find a single example. all the example are using cloud fire store.

Comment: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#0.

Comment: Already go through this.its about Fire Store not FireBase RealTime Database

Comment: I do understand that there is no example. I feel if you go through the API reference you can easily integrate it. https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/firebase_database/latest/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can refer to [this](https://medium.com/flutterpub/realtime-database-in-flutter-bef0f29e3378) medium article, they have explained how to use StreamBuilders with Firebase RTDB.

In the meantime, here's a piece code derived from the same article...

```
//first make a reference to your firebase database

var recentJobsRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance
.reference()
.child('recent')
.orderByChild('created_at') 
.limitToFirst(10);

//then use StreamBuilders like this

StreamBuilder(
stream: recentJobsRef.onValue,
builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
if(snapshot.hasData) => return "Has Data";
else if(snapshot.hasError) => return "Error";
}
```